# How to make a performance test fail if it's too slow?

Tags: ios, swift, performance, performance-testing

I'd like my test to fail if it runs slower than 0.5 seconds but the average time is merely printed in the console and I cannot find a way to access it. Is there a way to access this data?

**Code**

```
//Measures the time it takes to parse the participant codes from the first 100 events in our test data.
func testParticipantCodeParsingPerformance()
{
    var increment = 0
    self.measureBlock
    {
        increment = 0
        while increment < 100
        {
            Parser.parseParticipantCode(self.fields[increment], hostCodes: MasterCalendarArray.getHostCodeArray()[increment])
            increment++
        }
    }
    print("Events measured: \(increment)")
}
```

**Test Data**

> [Tests.ParserTest testParticipantCodeParsingPerformance]' measured [Time, seconds] average: 0.203, relative standard deviation: 19.951%, values: [0.186405, 0.182292, 0.179966, 0.177797, 0.175820, 0.205763, 0.315636, 0.223014, 0.200362, 0.178165]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to set a baseline for your performance test. Head to the Report Navigator:

[image: Report Navigator]

and select your recent test run. You'll see a list of all your tests, but the performance ones will have times associated with them. Click the time to bring up the Performance Result popover:

[image: Performance Result]

The "Baseline" value is what you're looking for--set it to 0.5s and that will inform Xcode that this test *should* complete in half a second. If your test is more than 10% slower than the baseline, it'll fail!

Comment: These have worked well but they only work locally on my machine, I'm using git for my project and all other users do not have their baselines set. Is there a way to include this baseline within a git project?

Comment: I found this which did the job
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46563991/957245

Answer (score 5):

The only way to do something similar to what you describe is setting a time limit graphically like @andyvn22 recommends.

But, if you want to do it completely in code, the only thing you can do is extend XCTestCase with a new method that measure the execution time of the closure and returns it to be used in an assertiong, here is an example of what you could do:

```
extension XCTestCase{
    /// Executes the block and return the execution time in millis
    public func timeBlock(closure: ()->()) -> Int{
        var info = mach_timebase_info(numer: 0, denom: 0)
        mach_timebase_info(&info)
        let begin = mach_absolute_time()

        closure()

        let diff = Double(mach_absolute_time() - begin) * Double(info.numer) / Double(1_000_000 * info.denom)
        return Int(diff)
    }
}
```

And use it with:

```
func testExample() {
    XCTAssertTrue( 500 < self.timeBlock{
        doSomethingLong()
    })
}
```