# How to share Xcode performance test baselines on git?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, performance-testing, xcode8

I have performance tests on Xcode with a baseline set as shown below.
[image]

These baselines appear to be locally saved (like breakpoints) so my changes to them are not transferred over git. When anyone other than myself runs my performance tests and they're too slow the tests do not fail. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Baselines are saved in `YourProject.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcbaselines/`, meaning you just need to *not* include it in your `.gitignore` file and you'll be able to add them to your remote.

(if you can't find that folder, right click your `.xcodeproj` file and click 'Show Package Contents')

Once that is done, everyone synchronising and running performance tests should have the baselines you set to compare against.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 13 baselines are saved in `YourProject.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcbaselines/`, but each baseline is specific to the device and simulator combo that you used to set the baseline. If someone else runs the performance tests on a machine with different specs it won't use the baseline you set.

As far as I can tell, there is no way to set the baselines from the command line so there is no way to set baselines on a headless CI server.

However if you don't use a headless CI server you can enable the "Treat missing baselines as test failures" build setting in Xcode. This will cause any performance test without a baseline set for the current configuration to fail, prompting the developer to set them manually.